# (No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe, ...) failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory

Tags: nagios

Getting this exception in Nagios GUI:

> (No output on stdout) stderr:
>   execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe, ...) failed. errno is 2:
>   No such file or directory

Could you please help me to overcome this issue?

I have a custom script to check.

Comment: Please, provide output of command `stat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe`.